# How do you troubleshoot a VPN that intermittently drops on Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, vpn, troubleshooting

My connection intermittently drops while connecting to a VPN. Is there a systemic process to follow to troubleshoot this? I haven't had any luck and it makes it very hard to use Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single systematic solution to solve all problems, but networking problems are often amenable to to iterative testing.

Some things you want to test, each of which could cause this problem, and each which can be tested individually -

1. Does the problem occur at a specific time ?
2. Does the problem occur when the IP address of the router changes (if it
   changes)
3. Does reducing the MTU fix the problem ?
4. Does the problem occur only when there is a default route through the VPN.
5. Is the date on the VPN client and server correct ?
6. Does the problem only happen from behind one Internet connection, or 
   from behind Internet connection.

Of-course, looking at the VPN log files will very often  give you information to help narrow down the problem space.

Similarly, using tools like MTR/WinMTR and iperf can help with diagnostics, routing and testing.